# The Double Integral of Charge Density with respect to Change in Area

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The double integral of charge density (in Coulombs per sq meter) with respect to change in area (dA) is just the total charge, correct?

I just want to make sure I am interpreting it correctly.

Comment: Have you thought of asking this question on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's correct. If the charge density is constant over the region, you can just multiply the area of the region by the charge density to find the total charge, but when the charge density varies continuously over the region, an integral is necessary.